# appendChild() not working in Chrome specifically. May not interpret as JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, appendchild, getelementsbytagname

I'm using an affiliate program which in this case means once a customer press the "order" button, he/she will get directed to the sellers website. The seller then registers that the customer came from OUR button, which is done by using a tracker that he registrates. This tracker gets executed on the "Order" button click, using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() {
        function injectFile(filePath) {
            var newScript = document.createElement('script');
            newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
            newScript.src = filePath;
            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(newScript);
        }

        $('#custom_form').on('success.form', function() {
            injectFile('https://example.com/&ti=' + Math.round((new Date().getTime() * Math.random())) + '&charset=ISO-8859-1');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I removed the actual URL and most of the parameters. ti represents an order ID that is needed for the reg to work, but it doesn't have to be valid. The above math generates a random number and inserts it.

By tracking the HTTP headers, I can confirm that this works in both Firefox and IE, since it requests the URL properly. In Chrome however, no request is registered and the seller won't see the customer coming from my end.

Sometimes the Chrome console displays this: "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html." However, this is just a warning and since it defines it as a script anyway it shouldn't affect the execution? Weird thing here is I don't get this error each time.

I have tried just about everything and I can't see why Chrome wouldn't be compatible with such a basic functionality. Is there a possible workaround or an actual fix to my issue?

Thanks in advance,
Fredrik

Comment: Are you sure event 'success.form' is always fired on Chrome?

Comment: The event seems to fire properly. I entered an alert("HEY); right after the event before the injectFile to debug it, and the message indeed does pop up.

Comment: Just wondering, same result if you append script to HEAD?

Comment: Wouldn't that disable the entire function since it requires the body to be loaded?

Comment: No because you are calling it inside DOM ready handler

Comment: Due to the restrictions of the CMS we're using, I'm not able to place it in the <head> tag.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad configuration of the Apache / Nginx configuration of the remote server.
The mime-type of the file is not "text/javascript".
But no effect on your code ;)

Comment: But it does interpret it as a script. And watching profiles in chrome it even successfully executes the injectFile function, but no HTTP request .. ?

Answer (score 0):

Try running your code in an incognito window or a fresh install of Chrome - some extensions block asynchronous script loading from advertising or tracking sites in a way that is hard to detect.

Comment: Thank you for your response but it does not seem to make a difference.